# PHP Heroku - Error code H10 (status 503)

Tags: php, heroku

I have deployed a simple PHP app on Heroku containing only one (PHP) script for my source code. I decided to write a function in a separate PHP script. After this, I was getting a `403 Forbidden Error` and this message was displayed on the url of my app: `Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server`. Because of this I created a text document called `Procfile` without any extension and I posted in it the following: `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/`.

However, now I am getting the following error on `heroku logs`:

```
2018-04-10T09:09:09.853483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/" host=************.herokuapp.com request_id=************ fwd="************" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-04-10T09:09:56.037642+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=************.herokuapp.com request_id=************ fwd="************" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

and the following message is displayed at the url of my app:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. 
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

My (main) PHP script on Heroku receives/hosts a webhook from Dialogflow and returns some information to it retrieved from a database. It looks like this:

```
<?php

$dbServername = '******************';
$dbUsername = '******************';
$dbPassword = '******************';
$dbName = '******************';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($method == 'POST') {
    $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($requestBody);

    $action = $json->result->action;
    $first_name = $json->result->contexts[0]->parameters->{'given-name'};
    $last_name = $json->result->contexts[0]->parameters->{'last-name'};
    $lifespan = $json->result->contexts[0]->lifespan;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM family WHERE name LIKE '%$first_name%$last_name%';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $person = $row;
        }

        switch ($action) {
            case 'Name':
                $speech = "$first_name is my" . $person["name"] . ".";
                break;
            case 'Location':
                $speech = "$first_name is living in {$person["location"]}.";
                break;
            default:
                $speech = "Please ask me something more relevant to my family";
                break;
        }
    } else {

        $speech = "Sorry, $first_name $last_name is not a member of my family.";
    }

    $response = new \stdClass();
    $response->speech = $speech;
    $response->displayText = $speech;
    $response->source = "agent";
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    echo "Method not allowed";
}
?>
```

**Why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?**

I do not know if this is relevant but I am also getting the following warning when I am entering `git push heroku master` at the terminal:

```
remote:  !     WARNING: Your Composer vendor dir is part of your Git repository.
remote:        This directory should not be under version control; only your
remote:        'composer.json' and 'composer.lock' files should be added, which
remote:        will let Composer handle installation of dependencies on deploy.
```

Comment: did you ever solve it?

Comment: Hmm, I guess yes since I run various PHP apps on Heroku since then but I do not remember what I did exactly.

Comment: The fact that I did not post an answer here may mean that it was not eventually so serious to be discussed further. But if I recall it sometime I  may post it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by checking if the root directory exists or not
You'll need to check you `Procfile`